# Switching between OS-es but only with 1 computer

Tags: windows, network-shares, session, multiple-desktop

I would like to know if it is possible to run 2 Windows OSs at same time.

Explanation:

I have a pretty "strong" PC. I bought a new SSD. I want to install on it a "new/fresh" Windows OS.
Then i would have 2 OSs. One of them will be used **only for working purposes** (business).

Is there any chance to switching between these systems? (SSDs)

How can i achieve this? Do i need a server? Or another full PC? If yes, what is the best solution?

Comment: Are the operating systems supposed to run simultaneously or one at a time? If you want them to run simultaneously, a virtual machine is the best option and if running them at the same time isn't required, you could choose between them in your PC's boot menu every time you boot (slightly better performance than a VM).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run multiple operating systems on one computer simultaneously requires a virtualizing platform like VMware Workstation or Hyper-V (Microsoft).

Both work - I continue to prefer VMware Workstation for its flexibility.

I have here 11 operating systems plus my Windows 10 host. Three of them are running right now (Windows 7, Kali Linux 2020.4 and Ubuntu Linux 20.04).

I am working here and posting from within Kali Linux (to keep my hand in Linux).

A good strong PC with a large fast SSD drive will do this with aplomb.  My laptop is i7, 16 GB of memory, 1 TB NVMe SSD drive.

So you can definitely do what you are trying to do.

**Note:**  With Windows, modern Windows require a separate license for each occurrence of the operating systems. So 2 Windows 10 systems on one computer require 2 licenses.